# Apply upper and lower bounds to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 lists that contain upper and lower limits for each column of a Pandas Dataframe
What is the best way to extract from the dataFrame data within the upper and lower bounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use indexing to filter out the values you don't want.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10), columns=['a'])
df = df.ix[(df.a > lower) & (df.a < upper)]
```

You could iterate over each column/bounds-list and apply the same filter.

```
columns = df.columns
for i, bounds in enumerate(zip(upper_bounds, lower_bounds)):
    upper, lower = bounds
    column = columns[i]
    df = df.ix[(df[column] > lower) & (df[column] < upper)]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 df[(df.column>=min_val) & (df.column<=max_val)]
```

parentheses and logical & are important.

Comment: You shouldn't use min and max as variable names, you overwrite the builtin python functions.